# fade in background jquery

Tags: jquery, background-image

I'm trying to fade some images on the background of my site but isn't working T_T .
Thanks in advance !

HTML :

```
<body>
    <div id="menu1"></div>
    <div id="menu2"></div>
    <div id="menu3"></div>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
body {
    background-color: #1f304e;
    background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: center 0px;
}
```

JQuery :

```
$('#menu1').click(function(){
    $(body).animate({background : url('images/bg1.jpg') }, 600);
}); 
$('#menu2').click(function(){
    $(body).animate({background : url('images/bg2.jpg') }, 600);
}); 
$('#menu3').click(function(){
    $(body).animate({background : url('images/bg3.jpg') }, 600);
});
```

Comment: use css instead of animate

Comment: Are you putting the click function in `document.ready()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly animate the background image property of an element. You can fade in an entire element though, so try to create a `div` that contains the image, and fade that in.

Try to mimic the background with a div instead:

CSS:

```
#bg {
  background-color: #1f304e;
  background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position: center 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="bg"></div>
  <div id="menu1"></div>
  <div id="menu2"></div>
  <div id="menu3"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#menu1').click(function(){
  $("#bg").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#bg").css({background : url('images/bg1.jpg') });
    $("#bg").fadeIn(300);
  }, 300);
}); 
$('#menu2').click(function(){
  $("#bg").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#bg").css({background : url('images/bg2.jpg') });
    $("#bg").fadeIn(300);
  }, 300);
}); 
$('#menu3').click(function(){
  $("#bg").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#bg").css({background : url('images/bg3.jpg') });
    $("#bg").fadeIn(300);
  }, 300);
});
```

This will fade out the background, swap the image, then fade it back in. If you want a proper crossfade, you will need at least two divs in the background.

Comment: I did the div "#bg" (i needed to magin -8 to fit the screen).
but i used :
        $('#bg').animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
                 $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(images/bg2.jpg)'}).animate({opacity: 1});
        });
it works almost perfect but the transition is white if i could fade in black it will fit.

Comment: you should set the body's margin to 0 to avoid the need for negative margins, and set the body's background color to black in order to have the "fade to black" effect

Comment: margin 0 didnt worked o.o so i had to use negative. black bg works ;)

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<div class="main"></div>
```

**css**

```
.main { 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;  
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; 
    transition: all 1s ease;  
    background-image: url(imagesrc);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**JS**

```
setTimeout(function() {

    $(".main").css("background-image", "url(imageSrc)");
}, 2000);
```

If you want to change background with multiple images then,

```
var backgroundPath = "images/";
var backgrounds = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"];
var i = 0;

setTimeout(function() {

   var timer = setInterval(function() {

       $(".main").css("background-image", "url(" + backgroundPath + backgrounds[i] + ")");

       i ++;

       if (i >= backgrounds.length) {

           i = 0;
       }

   }, 2000);

 }, 3000);
```

Change the css and js according to your requirements. Cheers!!