# Add CSS3-transition to child object

Tags: css, hover, background-image, css-transitions

So I have a -tag and within it is a div. The div has a background image that appears when hovering.
I would like to add a transition to this affect, though I can't get it working.

HTML

```
<a class="thumbs">
  <div class="thumbsText">
    Some text
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbsText{
  -webkit-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}

.thumbs a:hover .thumbsText{
  background-image: url(images/shadow.png);
}
```

Comment: `background-image` is not a transitionable or animatable property. You would have to use something else. Also the selector is wrong for the `hover` as the class `thumbs` is on the `a`.

Comment: Ah ok! There's no jQuery to do this?
Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825194/fade-in-background-jquery

Comment: I am not much into jQuery mate, so can't comment much on that. Maybe you can add the jQuery tag to the question and then see the response.

Comment: @CarlPapworth possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition - please use search before asking next time.

Comment: @easwee cheers, kind of threw it out in the heat of the moment :D

Comment: You don't need all those vendor prefixes any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a transition to a `background-image`. What you can do however is set the background image to a `:before` pseudo-element, and transition the opacity of that element:

```css
.thumbsText {
    position: relative;
}

.thumbsText:before{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/150/150);    
    bottom: 0;
    content: ' ';
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.thumbs:hover .thumbsText::before{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="thumbs">
   <div class="thumbsText">
      Some text
   </div>
</a>
```

Also your selector is not entirely correct. You are trying to select a link inside `.thumb` with your rule (`.thumb a:hover`), while those are the same element. I removed the `a` from my selector.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that out!
No that's true, in my original code the `<a>` is inside a `div.thumb`, I just printed out the example html wrong here :)
Thanks for your help!