# How do I put a fade effect on a jquery background effect?

Tags: jquery, hover, click, effect

Hi I would like to use a fade in effect on this jquery and have it appear on touch devices on click.

```
  $('#one').hover(function() {
    $('#one_text').css('background-color', '#fdb913');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('#one_text').css('background-color', '');
  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825194/fade-in-background-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('#one').hover(function() {
    $('#one_text').css('background-color', '#fdb913').fadeOut( 100 );
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('#one_text').css('background-color', '').fadeIn( 500 );
  });
```

See Plunker 
https://plnkr.co/edit/tfYEihJ8Z2SfXP1ShAKL?p=preview